# How can I count records with lower values in a field in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to say something like this:

```
select 
    AnswerText, 
    count(select * from @temp b where b.Ordinal < a.Ordinal) as Idx 
from @temp a
```

But of course I can't put a `select` statement inside a `count` function. So how can I get a count of all records with lower `Ordinal` values? Or is there a better way to determine the index of a record within a list?

Answer (score 2):

Move the count to the subquery:

```
select AnswerText,
       (select count(*) from @temp b where b.Ordinal < a.Ordinal) as Idx
from @temp a;
```

However, what you really want is probably `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by ordinal) as idx
from @temp t;
```